# Oracle APEX Commonwealth Bank Online Payments

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

You can pay with a Credit Card via CBA B-Point PHP,

```
//Create the client
$client = new SoapClient("https://www.bpoint.com.au/evolve/service.asmx?WSDL");
//Create a transaction request
$trans = array(
"Amount" => 1000,
"CardNumber" => "5123456789012346",
"CRN1" => "Tester",
"CRN2" => "",
"CRN3" => "",
"CVC" => "123",
"ExpiryDate" => "0513",
"PaymentType" => "PAYMENT",
"TxnType" => "INTERNET_ANONYMOUS",
"MerchantReference" => "OnlineBikeStore",
"OriginalTransactionNumber" => "");
//Webcall to process the payment
$pay = $client->ProcessPayment(array('username' =>"myusername", 'password' => "mypassword", 'merchantNumber' => "0000000000000000", 'txnReq' => $trans));
```

Are the URL and Action used here correct?

```
-- Get the XML response from the web service.
  l_xml := APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_request(
    p_url      => 'https://www.bpoint.com.au/evolve/service.asmx',
    p_action   => 'https://www.bpoint.com.au/evolve/service.asmx?WSDL',
    p_envelope => l_envelope
  );
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay so what exactly is the question here?

Comment: So, have you tried that sample code?  What errors are you getting?  How is your PHP output getting into APEX parameter `l_envelope`?

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 points.

First one is, did you create the corresponding ACL to reach that external domain? All connections are closed by default in Oracle.

Second one, another option is to use utl_http.begin_request instead APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_request, it's easier to manipulate and read the response.

In my blog I have some examples of this function begin_request and you can use it with GET or POST methods.

https://apex-developers.com/2019/06/02/web-services-en-oracle-apex-19/

Let me know if you need more help.